# Can't figure out why a table element is mis-positioning

Tags: html, html-table

I am working on a webpage, that I didn't build but am modifying. I am rather new to HTML coding. My problem is that I have a table with three columns and one row. Each column contains one or two pictures over some text. For some reason, the first column (the left column) drops down lower than the rest and I can't figure out why. Sorry, I'm not allowed to post a picture, so you can't see what I'm talking about. I hope I've described the problem well enough.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="cleandraindry" style="z-index:-999;">
    <div id="hidehere" style="float:left;margin:10px 0 0 99px;width:600px;">
         <span style="color:#db6918;font-family:Futura-Bold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;font-weight:900;text-transform:uppercase;padding-bottom:8px;width:600px;"> 
            Emerald ash borer hides here
         </span>
         <br><br />
         <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;width:354px;">The emerald ash borer is not always visible as the adults are small enough to fit on the head of a penny. The larvae burrow under the bark and through the wood, often going unseen until the ash tree begins to die. Because larvae and pupae can survive for long periods even in cut wood, a primary way to ensure that you don't spread emerald ash borers is to not move firewood from areas with a known infestation, particularly across state lines. </span>
     </div><br />
     <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
     <!-- <div id="boat" style="margin:20px;"> 
         <img src="firewood_stack_900.jpg" style="display:block;margin:auto;"/>
     </div> -->
     <div>
         <table style="display:block;margin:-10px 0 0 69px;">
             <tr>
                 <td style="width:220px;padding:30px;">
                     <img src="EAB&penny_220x148.jpg"; style="margin:0 0 10px 0";/>
                     <br />
                     <img src="adulteab_220.jpg"; style="margin:0 0 5px 0";/>
                     <span style="color:#db6918;font-family:Futura-Bold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;font-weight:900;text-transform:uppercase;">
                         adults
                     </span><br />
                     <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;">
                         1/2 inch long and 1/8 inch wide, metallic emerald green in coloration. Can be distinguished from other similar boring beetles by the disinctive reddish top surface of their abdomen (under the wings). Females lay 50-100 eggs in bark crevices. (Photo: David Cappaert [top], Howard Russell, both Bugwood.org)
                     </span>  
                 </td>   
                 <td style="width:220px;padding:30px;">
                     <img src="canopydieback_220.jpg"; style="margin:0 0 10px 0";/>
                     <span style="color:#db6918;font-family:Futura-Bold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;font-weight:900;text-transform:uppercase;">
                         Canopy
                     </span><br />
                     <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px">
                         As the emerald ash borer larvae feed, the canopy leaves die from the top down. The feeding larvae also trigger new branches and shoots on trunk and branches. (Photo: Daniel Herms, Bugwood.org)
                     </span>
                 </td>
                 <td style="width:220px;padding:30px;">
                     <img src="feedinggallery_220.jpg"; style="margin:0 0 10px 0"; />
                     <span style="color:#db6918;font-family:Futura-Bold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;font-weight:900;text-transform:uppercase;">
                         girdling
                     </span><br />
                     <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px">
                         Larvae burow into the phloem (bark) and sapwood, creating S-shaped galeries under the bark and blocking nutrient flow. This eventually kills the tree. (Photo: James W. Smith, USDA APHIS PPQ, Bugwood.org)
                     </span>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the `br` line here:

```
 <img src="EAB&penny_220x148.jpg" ; style="margin:0 0 10px 0" ;/>
 <br />
```

The `<br />` will create a gap even if that image isn't displayed. Remove the line and the titles should line up.
I would also suggest adding to the styles: `vertical-align:top;`

```
style="vertical-align:top;width:220px;padding:30px;"
```

to ensure they align at the top.

Additionally to improve the code there are issues such as:

```
<img src="EAB&penny_220x148.jpg"; style="margin:0 0 10px 0";/>
```

which should be

```
<img src="EAB&penny_220x148.jpg" style="margin:0 0 10px 0;" />
```

*Note the removed semi-colon and style semi-colon moved inside the quotes.
Most of the image tags appear to have this issue.

Comment: I was using the <br /> to separate the two pictures vertically, but of course the margin does that.  So removing the <br /> didn't solve the problem.  However, adding the vertical_align did!  Thanks SO much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If you could up arrow and/or mark this as a solution that would be great :)